# initramfs - need to edit text file

Tags: text-editor, initrd

I'm stuck in initramfs on Linux Mint v15 and I need to edit /bin/grub/grub/cfg.  I have the sda1 device mounted but not sure what to do to edit.  I try exec ./usr/bin/vi and it throws a kernel panic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now there are options to do. I followed the below path:

1. Make a temp directory.
2. Mount the root filesystem (/) on the temp directory.
3. Then chroot it.

   (initramfs) mkdir /mnt

   (initramfs) mount /dev/device-name /mnt

   (initramfs) chroot /mnt

   $ vi

Comment: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/464071/how-can-i-edit-a-file-if-there-is-no-vi-vim-joe-etc) contain another make sense answer.